# Expectation and covariance of Gaussian vector given norm constraint

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let ${\bf{x}}\sim {\cal{N}}({\bf{\mu}},\sigma^2{\bf{I}}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$

I am wondering if I can find an analytical expression for the expectation and covariance of ${\bf{x}}$ given that $\frac{||\bf{x}||^2}{\sigma^2}$ crosses some threshold $\gamma$:

1. $\mathrm{E}[{\bf{x}}| \frac{||\bf{x}||^2}{\sigma^2}> \gamma  ]$
2. $\mathrm{Cov}[{\bf{x}}| \frac{||\bf{x}||^2}{\sigma^2}> \gamma  ]$.

I notice that
$\frac{||\bf{x}||^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_n(\lambda)$ where the non-centrality parameter is $\lambda=\frac{\bf{\mu^T\mu}}{\sigma^2}$.

So far, I managed to show that for the case where $\bf{\mu}=0$ $\mathrm{E}[{\bf{x}}| \frac{||\bf{x}||^2}{\sigma^2}> \gamma  ]=0$ and that $\forall i\neq j: \mathrm{E}[x_ix_j | \frac{||\bf{x}||^2}{\sigma^2}> \gamma  ]=0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are trivially overcomplicating: define $a = \gamma \sigma^2$ and you have a single parameter instead of two. 
Apart from that, the result is probably quite difficult/messy for $\mu \ne 0$

Comment: You are correct, but both $\gamma$ and $\sigma^2$ are known, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I said "trivially". It really matters that your question is mathematically neat, it helps to get answers.